# Can I make an infinte sum using rational numbers that makes an irrational but not transcendental number?

Tags: sequences-and-series, continued-fractions, summation-method

I looked a lot on the internet for examples and I tried to do it myself, but I haven't seen any infinite sums of rational numbers that equal for example something like square root of 10 or cube root of 2.

The famous ones that I've seen end up adding to integers or a fraction of pi, but I haven't seen any irrational numbers that aren't transcendental.

Is there a method where I can pick an irrational number and then make an infinite sum using rational numbers where they are equal?

like the continued fraction for square root of 10 is 3.666666666... can I use that somehow to make an expression for the infinite sum using rational numbers? What about if it goes to a cube root?

I'd also really like it if someone could make my question a little clearer using the right math words and such, I really did my best to describe it.

Comment: $\sqrt{2}=1+0.4+0.01+0.004+0.0002+...$

Comment: See the binomial series expansion.

Comment: @Starfall "See the binomial series expansion." What for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a decimal expansion for your irrational number. We'll take $\sqrt2=1.41421\dots$ for example.

Then we can write

$$\sqrt{2}=1+\frac{4}{10}+\frac{1}{100}+\frac{4}{1000}+\frac{2}{10000}+\frac{1}{100000}+\dots$$

Each term in our sequence is rational (and moreover it is clear how to apply this idea to get an infinite sum of rationals to converge to any real number).

Edit: and I now see @BigbearZzz made this exact remark in a comment

Edit 2: Alternatively from the identity $$\frac1{\sqrt{1-4x}}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\binom{2n}{n}x^n,$$ we can plug in $x=\frac{1}{8}$ and get $$\sqrt{2}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\binom{2n}{n}\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^n$$

Comment: I didn't do a very good job describing my question, I wanted to know if there was a way I could do something like the infinite sum of 1/n^2 which is equal to pi^2/6 .  Like make a compact form, the one that you wrote I already knew.  Is it not possible to make it compact for irrational numbers that aren't transcendental?

Comment: @user337560 It depends a little what you mean by a compact form - for example we could write $$\sqrt2=1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\left\lfloor10^n\sqrt2\right\rfloor}{10^n}-\frac{\left\lfloor10^{n-1}\sqrt2\right\rfloor}{10^{n-1}}$$

Comment: That would work except that there are irrational numbers in the compact form instead of only rational ones.  Is it possible to make the compact form using only rational numbers?  I did my best to convey it in the title question but I don't think I've done a very good job with the confusion I've caused.

Comment: @user337560 Each of the terms in the compact form given is rational (note the use of the floor function) . . .

Comment: @user337560 You could also use the Fibonacci sequence - letting $F_0$, $F_1=1$ and $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$. We know the ratio between these numbers converges to the golden ratio, so we could say $$\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}=\frac{F_1}{F_0}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}-\frac{F_n}{F_{n-1}}\right)$$ Notice that we have just $$\frac{F_1}{F_0}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^k \left(\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}-\frac{F_n}{F_{n-1}}\right)=\frac{F_{k+1}}{F_k}$$

Comment: Though maybe the above is also unsatisfactory because if we actually write down an explicit formula for the partial sum, it would include the golden ratio already. hmm..

Comment: @NoahSchweber I think perhaps user337560 means that no irrational number should appear in the text of the expression (like $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}$ can be written with only rational numbers and a summation notation)

Comment: @user337560 Oh, I have got one. We have the identity $$\frac1{\sqrt{1-4x}}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\binom{2n}{n}x^n$$ so we can plug in $x=\frac{1}{8}$ and get $$\sqrt{2}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\binom{2n}{n}\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^n$$ I'll add this one to the actual answer.

Comment: Peter I think the golden ratio one works and so does the other one you posted.  If you can put either one as a comment I'll select it as the answer.  Where did that identity come from so I can look into it further.

Comment: @user337560 The above came from a generating function. It's nontrivial to dive right into an explanation of how it all works, but you could start here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient

Comment: @user337560 Additionally, I don't think (though obviously it is up to you) that my answer is currently worthy of being accepted as I have just given a relatively nice expression for a single number, and I'm confident that more general answers exist - I'm just not coming up with one.

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt 2 = (1+1)^{1/2}$

by the binomial theorem:

$(1+a)^{1/2}$$ = 1 + (1/2) 1^{-1/2}a-(1/8) 1^{-3/2}a^2+ (3/48) a^3\cdots$

coefficient of the $n^{th}$ term:

$c_0 = 1\\c_n = c_{n-1}\frac{(1/2-n)}{n}$

when $n\ge 3, 
c_n = (-1)^{n+1}\frac{1*3*5*7...(n-2)}{2*4*6*8\cdots n}
$

More generally, can you find a series that converges to the alegraic (non-trancendental) number of your choosing?

If $q$ is an algebraic number, $p(q) = 0$ for some polynomial $p$.

And Newtons method will frequenty (but not always) generate a sequence that coverges to q.

$x_n = x_{n-1} - \dfrac {p(x_{n-1})}{p'(x_{n-1})}$